# Как перевести программы на другой аудио канал в Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Необходимо назначить для программы другой канал звука. При условии, что в самой программе такого функционала нет.

Вариант с переключением дефолтноно канала, перед запуском нужной софтины не подходит.

Перевести нужно только конкретную программу, а не все сразу.

Comment: Немного не понятно, нужно **поменять** устройство вывода звука только для одной программы или **изменить** параметры аудиоустройства, влияя на каналы выводимого звука? Если первое, то должны помочь программы типа CheVolume или audio-router.

Comment: Необходимо изменить выходной канал программы, чтоб на дефолтном канале ее слышно не было, а на том что необходим, было

Comment: Например у скайпа есть такая функция из коробки, просто в настройках меняешь канал. Но не весь софт так может.

Comment: Вот я из Ваших объяснений не понял ,что такое канал устройства? С точки зрения ОС есть устройства вывода звука. А уж какими свойствами оно (устройство) обладает: каналами, мощностью, частотой дискретизации операционной системе, в принципе, не важно - за это отвечает драйвер устройства. Поэтому повторю вопрос, что такое канал устройства? И да, устройств вывода может быть несколько.

Comment: Я просто не знаю как правильно сказать, чтоб вы меня поняли. Каналами я называл то, что находится в списке "Устройства воспроизведения"

Comment: Представленный список в разделе воспроизведение - это и есть список устройств. Как я уже ответил в 1-ом комментарии, проще использовать готовые программные решения: CheVolume или audio-route. Возможно, первая программа является платной.

Comment: Да, CheVolume решает задачу.